# to modify nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

can someone help me out to access the objects that nested in hello ?
I've tried `greetings.hello.portuguese`, but it s `undefined`.

```
const greetings = {
  hello: [{
    english: 'hi',
    french: 'bonjour',
    portuguese: 'oi'
  }],
  goodbye: [{
    english: 'bye',
    french: 'au revoir',
    portuguese: 'tchau'
  }]
};
```

Comment: `greetings.hello[0].portuguese`

Comment: Why are `hello` and `goodbye` arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two arrays inside **`greentings`** which are **`hello`** and **`goodbye`**, if you want to access **`portuguese`** you need to take it from the first array which is index 0.

**CODE**

```js
 const greetings = {
  hello: [{
    english: 'hi',
    french: 'bonjour',
    portuguese: 'oi'
  }],
  goodbye: [{
    english: 'bye',
    french: 'au revoir',
    portuguese: 'tchau'
  }]
};
console.log(greetings.hello[0].portuguese);
```

Comment: Thank you, cuz I m newbie at JS.